# ion-select in Ionic Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, select, ion-select

I want to select a Restaurant name and after i select it to have on the page only the food from that restaurant, but it doesn't work. After I select one restaurant from the list nothing happens.

Here is my **.html** file :

```
  <ion-item class="restaurant">
    <ion-label>Restaurant</ion-label>
    <ion-select class="RestaurantSelect" [(ngModel)]="restaurant">
      <ion-select-option *ngFor="let restaurant of restaurants" [value]="restaurant">
        {{restaurant.name}}
      </ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>


  <ion-list>
  <ion-item lines="none" *ngFor="let f of restaurant; let i=index">
<!--    <ng-container *ngFor="let f of rest">-->
    <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
      <ion-img [src]="f.photo"></ion-img>
    </ion-thumbnail>

    <ion-label>{{f.food.name}}
      <ion-buttons>
        <ion-button  color="dark">Edit
          <ion-icon slot="start" name="create"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
        <ion-button color="dark" (click)="remove(i)">Delete
          <ion-icon slot="start" name="trash"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
      </ion-buttons>
    </ion-label>
<!--    </ng-container>-->

  </ion-item>

  </ion-list>

  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

I have do declare an array of arrays : each restaurant has more types of food, and also foods have more fields like name, description, price, etc
this is how i declared the arrays in my **.ts** file :

````
  restaurants: any[] =[
    {
      id:1,
      name: 'Restaurant1',
      food:[
        {
          id:1,
          name:'Burger',
          description:'good',
          price:10, 
          photo:'img1.jpg',
        },
        {
          id:2,
          name:'Pizza',
          description:'nice',
          price:20,
          photo:'img2.jpg',
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      id:2,
      name: 'Restaurant2',
      food: [{
        id:3,
        name:'Burger',
        description:'good',
      },
        {
          id:4,
          name:'Ice',
          description:'nice',
        },],
    },
  ] ```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your responses!
````

Comment: Can you provide the ts code that handles restaurant picking from the ion-select, i.e. the code that sets the value of 'restaurant' for listing of the details (unless you expect it to depend on dropdown pick, which would be wrong with the code you provided)? Also, there is no f.photo field in the restaurant object and you won't get f.food.name because f.food is an array, not an object, so you'll have to call the name by food index.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this in template:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Restaurant</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="chosenRestaurantIdx">
      <ion-option *ngFor="let restaurant of restaurants; let i = index" [value]=i>
        {{ restaurant.name }}
      </ion-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>

<ng-container *ngIf="chosenRestaurantIdx != null">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let food of restaurants[chosenRestaurantIdx].food; let i = index">

        <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
            <img [src]="food.photo"/>
        </ion-thumbnail>

        <ion-label>{{ food.name }}</ion-label>
        <ion-button color="primary" (click)="edit(i)">Edit
            <ion-icon slot="start" name="create"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
        <ion-button color="dark" (click)="remove(i)">Delete
            <ion-icon slot="start" name="trash"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>

    </ng-container>        
</ng-container>
```

And introduce a var to ts:

```
chosenRestaurantIdx: number = null;
```

Add methods to ts as placeholders for edit/remove button clicks:

```
edit(index){
    console.log("edit index:",index);
  }

  remove(index){
    console.log("delete index:",index);
  }
```

Finally, of course, you'll have to style it all.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ion change event which triggered after each change on your select options.
Template:

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="chosenRestaurantIdx" (ionChange)='selectionChanged($event)'>
  <ion-option *ngFor="let restaurant of restaurants; let i = index" [value]=i>
    {{ restaurant.name }}
  </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

Typscript:

```
selectionChanged(data:any){
let newSelection = data.detail.value;
// add your code logic here
}
```